# How can I keep the momentum when jumping in air?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some code that handles jumping and moving:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FPSMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float jumpForce;
    [SerializeField] Transform groundChecker;
    [SerializeField] float checkRadius;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] float speed;
    [SerializeField] float resistance;
    [SerializeField] float sprintMultiplier = 1.5f;

    Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bool IsOnGround() {
            Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(groundChecker.position, checkRadius, groundLayer);
            if (colliders.Length > 0) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveBy = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        
        float actualSpeed = speed;
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsOnGround()) {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
            actualSpeed *= sprintMultiplier;
        }

        if (IsOnGround() == false){
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveBy.normalized * actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime / resistance);
        }
        if (IsOnGround() == true){
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveBy.normalized * actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

But when you jump and you hit wit slows you down. How can I make it so you are only slowly gain speed but not lose speed when you press w. Whiteout the code at the bottom that does different speed in the air it just goes the same speed in the air than on the ground which is unrealistic.

Comment: You're dividing `Time.deltaTime` by `resistance`. Try dividing `actualSpeed` by `resistance` instead, like this: `transform.position + moveBy.normalized * (actualSpeed / resistance) * Time.deltaTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the original does not support what I am trying to do in the way that if you stop pressing a movement key it will stop the player. which means what I am trying to do to keep the momentum is impossible with the code provided.
Example:

```cs
float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
float z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
```

These values would be 0 if you are not pressing anything, so...

```cs
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveBy.normalized * actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime / resistance);
```

Since the moveBy value would be 0 the player would stop because 0 * any number is 0.

If you want the movement to be the same as what I was trying to do I would recommend Dani's tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAC8U9-dTZU